# Docker inside docker with gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have created a gitlab runner.

I have choosen docker executor and an ubuntu default image.

I have put this at the top of my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest
```

I was thinking that gitlab-ci will load ubuntu image by default if there are no "images" directive in .gitlab-ci.yml file.

But, there is something strange: I am wondering now if gitlab-ci is not creating an ubuntu container and then creating a dotnet container inside the ubuntu container.

Here is a very ugly test i have done on gitlab server: I have removed /usr/bin/docker file and i have replaced it by a script which logs arguments.

This is very strange because jobs still working and i have nothing in my log file....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu image is indeed used if you didn't specify image but you did and your jobs should be run on the dotnet container without ever spinning up the ubuntu.

Your test behaves the way it does because `docker` is the client while `dockerd` is the deamon that gitlab runner actually calls.

If you want to check what's going on you should rather call `docker ps` to get a list of running containers.